Issues with COM between a .NET 8+ project and a .NET Framework one
I tried making a .NET 8+ COM Host whose interface has an IEnumerable that under the hood is an iterator method utilizing yield statements, to be used from a .NET Framework v4.8 project.
My interface is the following:
    [ComVisible(true)]
    [Guid("<random-guid>")]
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]
    public interface IDemoReader
    {
        IEnumerable<string> GetData();
    }

I somehow got to the point where my .NET Framework program made an instance of IDemoReader, but the return type I had was string[], as I had to manually create a .tlb file from C++, and then used another tool called tlbimp that generated me a .dll out of my .tlb which I could reference in the .NET Framework application.
That .dll for some reason changed the return type to be a string[] instead of IEnumerable<string>. I'm guessing generics are a no-no?
The moment the method was called, the .NET Framework process terminated with the following error:
Unhandled Exception: System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalDirectiveException: Cannot marshal 'return value': Non-blittable generic types cannot be marshaled.
   at DemoReader.Interop.IDemoReader.GetData()
   at Tester.Framework.Program.Main(String[] args)


COM is language agnostic, ie: Generics cannot be seen by COM. You can just declare GetData as object[] GetData and it should work (but do send a real object[], not an enumerator or an array of strings). PS1: ComVisible is for classes, use ComImport for interfaces. PS2: you don't need a tlb if you're all inprocess w/o complex threading. PS3: your error is strange.

https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/runtime/interopservices/ComTypes/ienumstring.cs,20
